# Loop through KStream object and print out it's value

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I am trying to follow one of the example codes for Kafka Stream, to ensure that my consumer is able to consume the topic correctly, I want to iterate and print out the event/value that it reads. From the documentations [here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html), I tried to use the foreach and the following is the code that I have got.

```
        @Component
        public static class PageCountSink {

        private final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());
        @StreamListener
        public void process(@Input((AnalyticsBinding.CONSUMER_IN)) KStream<String, PageViewEvent> event) {

            event
                    .foreach((key,value) -> log.info("Test"));

        }
```

And I get this error :-

```
2019-10-02 16:59:17.866 ERROR 30553 --- [-StreamThread-2] o.a.k.s.p.i.AssignedStreamsTasks         : stream-thread [consumer-2-453a13f7-6551-4d6a-b692-6d35c9a57195-StreamThread-2] Failed to process stream task 0_0 due to the following error:

java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class com.example.analytics.PageViewEvent (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; com.example.analytics.PageViewEvent is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamPeek$KStreamPeekProcessor.process(KStreamPeek.java:42) ~[kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode$1.run(ProcessorNode.java:50) ~[kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.runAndMeasureLatency(ProcessorNode.java:244) ~[kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:133) ~[kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:143) ~[kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:126) ~[kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:90) ~[kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamMapValues$KStreamMapProcessor.process(KStreamMapValues.java:41) ~[kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode$1.run(ProcessorNode.java:50) ~[kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.runAndMeasureLatency(ProcessorNode.java:244) ~[kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:133) ~[kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:143) ~[kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:126) ~[kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:90) ~[kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.process(SourceNode.java:87) ~[kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:302) ~[kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedStreamsTasks.process(AssignedStreamsTasks.java:94) ~[kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.process(TaskManager.java:409) ~[kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.processAndMaybeCommit(StreamThread.java:964) ~[kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:832) ~[kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:767) ~[kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:736) ~[kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:na]

2019-10-02 16:59:17.879 ERROR 30553 --- [-StreamThread-2] o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread         : stream-thread [consumer-2-453a13f7-6551-4d6a-b692-6d35c9a57195-StreamThread-2] Encountered the following error during processing:

java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class com.example.analytics.PageViewEvent (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; com.example.analytics.PageViewEvent is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamPeek$KStreamPeekProcessor.process(KStreamPeek.java:42) ~[kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode$1.run(ProcessorNode.java:50) ~[kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.runAndMeasureLatency(ProcessorNode.java:244) ~[kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:133) ~[kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:143) ~[kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:126) ~[kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:90) ~[kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamMapValues$KStreamMapProcessor.process(KStreamMapValues.java:41) ~[kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode$1.run(ProcessorNode.java:50) ~[kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.runAndMeasureLatency(ProcessorNode.java:244) ~[kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:133) ~[kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:143) ~[kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:126) ~[kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:90) ~[kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.process(SourceNode.java:87) ~[kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:302) ~[kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedStreamsTasks.process(AssignedStreamsTasks.java:94) ~[kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.process(TaskManager.java:409) ~[kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.processAndMaybeCommit(StreamThread.java:964) ~[kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:832) ~[kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:767) ~[kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:736) ~[kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:na]
```

Below are the relevant snippets for this consumer

```
    interface AnalyticsBinding {

        String CONSUMER_IN = "pcin" ;

        @Input(CONSUMER_IN)
        KStream<String, PageViewEvent> consumerIn();

    }

    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    class PageViewEvent {
        private String userId, page;
        private int randNum;
        private long duration;
    }
```

Would appreciate if anyone can point me out what I'm missing.
Thanks

Comment: What version of spring cloud stream? If you can upgrade to the latest milestones of 3.0, then the Serdes are automatically inferred on the inbound and outbound.

Comment: thanks @sobychacko, as you suggested it works when i changed the spring cloud dependencies version to  Greenwich.SR3

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it doesn't know how to deserialize to PageViewEvent. You may have configured it to use `StringSerializer` as default. In that case, you would need to define the Serdes for your PageViewEvent type.